# How to train a CNN model?

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

When trying to train the CNN model, I came across a code shown below:

```
def train(n_epochs, loaders, model, optimizer, criterion):

    for epoch in range(1,n_epochs):
        train_loss = 0
        valid_loss = 0

        model.train()
        for i, (data,target) in enumerate(loaders['train']):

            # zero the parameter (weight) gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()            
            # forward pass to get outputs
            output = model(data)            
            # calculate the loss
            loss = criterion(output, target)            
            # backward pass to calculate the parameter gradients
            loss.backward()            
            # update the parameters
            optimizer.step()
```

Can someone please tell me why is the second for loop used? 
i.e; `for i, (data,target) in enumerate(loaders['train']):`

And why `optimizer.zero_grad()` and `optimizer.step()` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` comes in handy when you need to prepare data batches (and perhaps shuffle them before every run).

  `data_train_loader = DataLoader(data_train, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)`

  In the above code, first `for-loop` iterates through the number of epochs while second loop iterates through the training dataset converted into batches via above code. For example:

  ```
  for batch_idx, samples in enumerate(data_train_loader):
      # samples will be a 64 x D dimensional tensor
      # batch_idx is each batch index
  ```

  Learn more about `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html).
- `Optimizer.zero_gradient()`: Before the backward pass, use the optimizer object to zero all of the gradients for the tensors it will update (which are the learnable weights of the model)
- `optimizer.step()`: We generally use `optimizer.step()` to make the gradient descent step. Calling the step function on an Optimizer makes an update to its parameters.

  Learn more about these from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html).

Comment: So if I have 1280 images in data_train_loader, batch_size = 64 means that 1280 images are divided into batches each with 64 images. And each batch is iterated over the second for loop for each epoch? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset

inps = torch.arange(1280*5, dtype=torch.float32).view(1280, 5)
tgts = torch.arange(1280*5, dtype=torch.float32).view(1280, 5)
dataset = TensorDataset(inps, tgts)

loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

for batch_ndx, sample in enumerate(loader):
    print(batch_ndx, end=' ')

Comment: run this code. yoy will get output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

Comment: which means 20*64 = 1280

Comment: oh okay...I ran the code you mentioned...thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Optimizer is used first to load the params like this (missing in your code):

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

This code

```
loss = criterion(output, target)
```

Is used to calculate the loss of a single batch where targets is what you got from a tuple `(data,target)` and data is used as the input for the model, where we got the `output`.

This step:

```
optimizer.zero_grad()
```

Will zero all the gradients found in the optimizer, which is very important on initialization.

The part

```
loss.backward()
```

Calculates the gradients, and the `optimizer.step()` updates our model weights and biases (parameters).

In PyTorch you typically use `DataLoader` class to load the trainging and validation sets.

```
loaders['train']
```

Is probable the full train set, which represents a single epoch.